# Any other operators that may convert algebraic function into transcendental ones

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request

As we know, the integral may convert or map a rational function or algebraic function into a transcendental one. Are there any other operators that may convert a rational function or algebraic function into transcendental one?

Further, are there any other operators that may convert transcendental function into algebraic or rational one like the derivative?

Those operators that are computable are most welcome.

Any reference is welcome. Review of such operators are most welcome.

Comment: What is your definition of transcendency?

Comment: @O.L.  the functions defined over complex number  that satisifies algebraic equation are algebraic,otherwise are transcendental

Comment: Then $\exp$, $\ln$ or the operation of taking the inverse function fit your queries.

Comment: What does this question have to do with functional analysis or several complex variables?